# iOS 7 Phonegap / Phonegap Build

Tags: cordova, ios7, phonegap-build

Ever since iOS 7 upgrade I have been having crashing problems with my phonegap app.
What is really strange is it's randomness. The app works with a phonegap build distribution then if I rebuild it with the same codebase not only does the file size changes, but the app crashes too.

Generally the app crashes all the time after logging in. The app then does a call to get some JSON and then parses it using jquery. Nothing too intensive.

This is the crash log from xcode organizer:

```
Incident Identifier: F38FA56C-D93C-48F8-A300-E49ED1D5A19B
CrashReporter Key:   b6c9a79fd3ca5bc4726d203881d6a3dfe649bd3d
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:             BetTracks [935]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/01252591-908A-4EBF-A5E0-47CB4662E84B/BetTracks.app/BetTracks
Identifier:          com.bettracks.BetTracks
Version:             1.0.4
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2013-10-05 18:35:03.019 +0100
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.2 (11A501)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xbadbec04
Triggered by Thread:  3

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x388fca84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x388fc87c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2e02f55c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2e02dcc2 __CFRunLoopRun + 858
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2df9853c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2df9831e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   GraphicsServices                0x32ccf2e6 GSEventRunModal + 134
7   UIKit                           0x3084f1e0 UIApplicationMain + 1132
8   BetTracks                       0x00090ec6 0x80000 + 69318
9   BetTracks                       0x00090ea0 0x80000 + 69280

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x388fcbb4 syscall_thread_switch + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x3897149c _os_lock_handoff_lock_slow + 48
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x3893493c szone_malloc_should_clear + 56
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x38937c96 malloc_zone_calloc + 74
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x38937c36 calloc + 46
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3835b6ce class_createInstance + 38
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x38844126 _os_object_alloc_realized + 18
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x38845b78 dispatch_mach_msg_create + 52
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x3884d5a2 _dispatch_kevent_mach_msg_recv + 194
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x3884b034 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 72
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x3884563e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 34

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x388fcbb4 syscall_thread_switch + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x3897149c _os_lock_handoff_lock_slow + 48
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3836ab28 objc_object::sidetable_clearDeallocating() + 20
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3835bc72 objc_destructInstance + 46
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3835be2e object_dispose + 10
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x3898111a -[OS_xpc_object _xref_dispose] + 42
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x3898121a _xpc_dictionary_node_free + 34
7   libxpc.dylib                    0x3898116c _xpc_dictionary_dispose + 24
8   libxpc.dylib                    0x38981138 _xpc_dispose + 12
9   libxpc.dylib                    0x3898111a -[OS_xpc_object _xref_dispose] + 42
10  libsystem_network.dylib         0x3894ea6c net_helper_connection_start + 244
11  libsystem_network.dylib         0x3894c11e tcp_connection_register_reachability + 170
12  libsystem_network.dylib         0x3894b250 __tcp_connection_start_block_invoke + 268
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x38844100 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x38848e72 _dispatch_queue_drain + 370
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x38845f96 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 38
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x3884974e _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 74
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x388499cc _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 52
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38973dfc _pthread_wqthread + 296
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38973cc0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3 Crashed:
0   WebCore                         0x35e54f72 WebCore::StyleResolver::loadPendingImages() + 1266
1   WebCore                         0x35e4e0e8 WebCore::StyleResolver::applyMatchedProperties(WebCore::StyleResolver::MatchResult const&, WebCore::Element const*) + 788
2   WebCore                         0x35e58738 WebCore::StyleResolver::styleForElement(WebCore::Element*, WebCore::RenderStyle*, WebCore::StyleSharingBehavior, WebCore::RuleMatchingBehavior, WebCore::RenderRegion*) + 948
3   WebCore                         0x35f5c868 WebCore::Document::styleForElementIgnoringPendingStylesheets(WebCore::Element*) + 92
4   WebCore                         0x35f5c7b6 WebCore::Element::computedStyle(WebCore::PseudoId) + 138
5   WebCore                         0x35f5c856 WebCore::Document::styleForElementIgnoringPendingStylesheets(WebCore::Element*) + 74
6   WebCore                         0x35f5c7b6 WebCore::Element::computedStyle(WebCore::PseudoId) + 138
7   WebCore                         0x35f5c856 WebCore::Document::styleForElementIgnoringPendingStylesheets(WebCore::Element*) + 74
8   WebCore                         0x35f5c7b6 WebCore::Element::computedStyle(WebCore::PseudoId) + 138
9   WebCore                         0x35fb4ae8 WebCore::ComputedStyleExtractor::propertyValue(WebCore::CSSPropertyID, WebCore::EUpdateLayout) const + 464
10  WebCore                         0x3605e216 WebCore::CSSComputedStyleDeclaration::getPropertyValue(WebCore::CSSPropertyID) const + 38
11  WebCore                         0x3605e1b6 WebCore::CSSComputedStyleDeclaration::getPropertyValue(WTF::String const&) + 22
12  WebCore                         0x360af740 WebCore::jsCSSStyleDeclarationPrototypeFunctionGetPropertyValue(JSC::ExecState*) + 256
13  JavaScriptCore                  0x2f0081e0 llint_native_call_trampoline + 62
14  JavaScriptCore                  0x2f011562 JSC::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 66
15  WebCore                         0x35e6e29a WebCore::JSMainThreadExecState::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 142
16  WebCore                         0x3605977c WebCore::JSEventListener::handleEvent(WebCore::ScriptExecutionContext*, WebCore::Event*) + 516
17  WebCore                         0x3601784a WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event*, WebCore::EventTargetData*, WTF::Vector<WebCore::RegisteredEventListener, 1ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow>&) + 482
18  WebCore                         0x35f16142 WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event*) + 174
19  WebCore                         0x360d14bc WebCore::EventTarget::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>) + 60
20  WebCore                         0x360d1444 WebCore::XMLHttpRequestProgressEventThrottle::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>) + 132
21  WebCore                         0x360d1398 WebCore::XMLHttpRequestProgressEventThrottle::dispatchReadyStateChangeEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>, WebCore::ProgressEventAction) + 32
22  WebCore                         0x360d118e WebCore::XMLHttpRequest::callReadyStateChangeListener() + 162
23  WebCore                         0x360d750e WebCore::XMLHttpRequest::didFinishLoading(unsigned long, double) + 230
24  WebCore                         0x35f63f5c WebCore::CachedResource::checkNotify() + 40
25  WebCore                         0x35f63ec2 WebCore::CachedRawResource::finishLoading(WebCore::ResourceBuffer*) + 150
26  WebCore                         0x35f63d8e WebCore::SubresourceLoader::didFinishLoading(double) + 110
27  WebCore                         0x35f63cf2 WebCore::didFinishLoading(_CFURLConnection*, void const*) + 130
28  CFNetwork                       0x2dcd0064 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 72
29  CFNetwork                       0x2dccec64 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 52
30  CFNetwork                       0x2dd00394 ___ZNK17CoreSchedulingSet13_performAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 16
31  CoreFoundation                  0x2df97f6e CFArrayApplyFunction + 34
32  CFNetwork                       0x2dc66f10 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 160
33  CFNetwork                       0x2dc66de2 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 218
34  CFNetwork                       0x2dc66c70 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 44
35  CoreFoundation                  0x2e02ff24 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
36  CoreFoundation                  0x2e02f3ea __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 202
37  CoreFoundation                  0x2e02dbda __CFRunLoopRun + 626
38  CoreFoundation                  0x2df9853c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
39  CoreFoundation                  0x2df9831e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
40  WebCore                         0x35efb7d8 RunWebThread(void*) + 416
41  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38975c5a _pthread_body + 138
42  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38975bca _pthread_start + 98
43  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38973ccc thread_start + 4
```

Since it doesn't crash in the simulator I don't have a clue where to start to debug it. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. But got crash in simulator also. This doesn't happen always, quite rear. I think it is related to webkit bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=127034 . It is fixed, but who knows when it will get into iOS7.x